# Magento Change purchase order status to processing

Tags: magento

[image: purchaseorder]

I need to make Purchase order payments a Processing Status so that those sales numbers show up on the dashboard. I've messed around with System > Order Statuses  but can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try openinig `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/system.xml` change node *purchaseorder >order_status > source_model* from `system_config_source_order_status_new` to `system_config_source_order_status` refresh Magento's cache and check.

Comment: I am using CCAvenue Payment Gateway,if payment successful stil status like pending,,, why not changing Processing... i have frequently faced this issue. May i know what are all the possibilities of error.

Comment: does the order have an invoice?

Comment: No, As you know after successfully paid the order status automatically changed to processing, then only we create invoice manually.